# Mocking Consecutive Calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest, contextmanager

I have some Python code in which I am calling the `with open()` context manager consecutively.

```
with open("f1") as f1:
    d1 = json.load(f1)
# some_more_logic_here
with open("f2") as f2:
    d2 = json.load(f2)
```

I am not sure how to mock these calls back to back. I am able to mock the first call with `mock_open(read_data=json.dumps(some_dictionary)`, but I am not able to mock the second context manager call with a different object than than the first. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get `mock_open` to play ball. But it's easy enough to do with lower-level mocks:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

from yourmodule import yourfunc


def test_yourfunc():
    first = MagicMock()
    second = MagicMock()
    first.__enter__.return_value.read.return_value = '{"k1": "v1"}'
    second.__enter__.return_value.read.return_value = '{"k2": "v2"}'
    with patch("yourmodule.open", side_effect=[first, second]):
        d1, d2 = yourfunc()
    assert d1 == {"k1": "v1"}
    assert d2 == {"k2": "v2"}
```